# Why can't I get the default site action to load?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I moved my Zend FW application from my Ubuntu PC (olddomain), to a Ubuntu Laptop.  Later I copied a version back to my Ubuntu PC and set it up under another virtual host (newdomain).  Now, when I go to the root of the new virtual host, I see the default apache host page (i.e.  "It Works!"), rather than the default page for my site.  Why is this so?

More information:

- When I navigate to newdomain/index.php, the correct page is shown
- The .htaccess file is the same for olddomain and newdomain
- The index.php file is the same for old and new domains
- I can't see any permission differences
- The /etc/hosts record is the same for both domains
- I have enabled the site (`a2ensite`), and restarted apache

What am I missing?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the virtual host configuration for the new domain, "front15":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName front15
    DocumentRoot /media/mainhdd/development/www/front/v15/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /media/mainhdd/development/www/front/v15/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Probably your configuration is incorrect. It seems Apache doesn't know index.php is your index file. Perhaps post your Apache config here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my /etc/hosts file I had multiple virtual hosts on one line, all pointing to the same IP (127.0.0.1).  I separated them out, one on each line, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities that I see causing this problem for you. One of them (the least likely possibility) is that you have a mod_rewrite rules in your .htaccess or apache.conf file that is specific to an IP or domain that's non-existent in this setup.

The more likely possibility is that your httpd `DirectoryIndex` directive for [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) has *index.html* listed first, **before** *index.php*. You have to remember that mod_dir uses `DirectoryIndex` arguments in order with the first argument taking precedence over the second argument and so on. So if you have `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` and there is an *index.html* file as well as an *index.php* file in your root web directory then httpd will use the *index.html* and not *index.php*, because that's the one it found first. This is the default setting, by the way.

So either remove index.html from that directory or change the `DirectoryIndex` directive in your httpd.conf or vhost file to use *index.php* before index.html and that way *index.php* files always take priority.

Comment: Hi Google Guy, I have double checked that I don't have mod_rewrite rules specific to a non-existent IP or domain.  Also, I don't have an index.html in the public directory, but I changed the order of the DirectoryIndex arguments anyhow and it made no difference.

Comment: Please look at your vhost file and make sure it isn't listening for a specific domain or IP that doesn't match your edit in the `hosts`

Comment: For eaxmple you would want to make sure your vhost file in */etc/apache2/sites-enabled* or wherever it's located to have `<VirtualHost newdomain:80>` where `newdomain` is whatever you changed in your `hosts` file. You also want to make sure it's pointing to the right directory for `DocumentRoot`